# How can I move a terminal screen from one workspace to another?

Tags: workspaces

I tried to drag a terminal screen from one workspace to another, and it didn't work.

Comment: Try selecting the window, then press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Right/Left/Down/Up (Compiz default keys)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the keyboard you can use `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Right/Left/Down/Up` depending on which direction you want to move it to. To do it graphically select the workspace switcher in the Launcher (or press `Super+s`) and drag it from workspace to workspace while in that view. Hit return when you're finished to return to the normal view.

Answer (score -2):

Just right click on the terminal's title bar and select "Move to Workspace ...". It works with any window.